# Using WMI `IWbemServices::ExecMethod` from Rust

Tags: winapi, rust, wmi, windows-rs

I'm trying to make WMI method calls (to the [xeniface](https://xenbits.xen.org/gitweb/?p=pvdrivers/win/xeniface.git;a=summary) driver).  The WMI crate does not yet wrap `ExecMethod` so we have to get down to `windows-rs` calls, and I'm having trouble getting it right.

Note, current wmi-rs 0.13.1 still uses windows-rs 0.48.

For reference, the Python equivalent of the code below would be the last line in:

```py
wmi_connection = wmi.WMI(namespace=r"root\wmi")
xs_base = wmi_connection.CitrixXenStoreBase()[0]
sid = xs_base.AddSession("MyNewSession")[0]
```

This function accepts the `CitrixXenStoreBase` object retrieved using the `wmi` crate.

1. Following [this post](http://win32easy.blogspot.com/2011/03/using-wmi-to-call-method-on-objects.html) I skipped the introspection call for in/out parameters (but essentially because my `GetMethod` call fails with WBEM_E_ILLEGAL_OPERATION, any clue why?  It could be useful for introspection and finding out how to get nte next steps right).
2. I still don't see how I should pass `in_params` to `ExecMethod` (and will likely have to use this to pass the session name)
3. I can't see how to extract info from `out_params` either, current attempt to extract `ReturnValue` fails with WBEM_E_NOT_FOUND.  I'd like to be able to introspect that `IWbemClassObject`, but could not find any details on how to do that

```rust
use windows::core::{BSTR, w};
use windows::Win32::System::{Com::VARIANT, Wmi::{IWbemClassObject, WBEM_FLAG_RETURN_WBEM_COMPLETE}};
use wmi::{Variant, WMIConnection, WMIError, WMIResult};

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
#[serde(rename_all = "PascalCase")]
struct CitrixXenStoreBase {
    #[serde(rename = "__Path")]
    __path: String,
    instance_name: String,
}

pub fn add_session(cnx: &WMIConnection,
                   object: CitrixXenStoreBase) -> WMIResult<usize>
{
    let mut wmi_object = None;
    let object_path: &str = object.__path.as_str();
    let object_path = BSTR::from(object_path);
    unsafe {
        let ret = cnx.svc.GetObject(&object_path,
                                    WBEM_FLAG_RETURN_WBEM_COMPLETE.0 as _,
                                    None,
                                    Some(&mut wmi_object),
                                    None);
        eprintln!("GetObject -> {:?}", ret);
        ret.expect("GetObject failure");
    }
    let wmi_object: IWbemClassObject = wmi_object.ok_or(WMIError::NullPointerResult)?;

    //let mut in_params: Option<IWbemClassObject> = None;
    let mut out_params: Option<IWbemClassObject> = None;

//    unsafe {
//        let ret = wmi_object.GetMethod(w!("AddSession"), 0, &mut in_params, &mut out_params);
//        eprintln!("GetMethod -> {:?}", ret);
//        ret.expect("GetMethod failure");
//    }

    unsafe {
        let ret = cnx.svc.ExecMethod(
            &BSTR::from(&object.__path),
            &BSTR::from("AddSession"),
            0,
            None,
            None, //in_params,
            Some(&mut out_params),
            None,
        );

        eprintln!("ExecMethod -> {:?}", ret);
        ret.expect("ExecMethod failure");
    }

    eprintln!("out_params: {:?}", out_params);
    let out_params = out_params.expect("AddSession should have output params");

    let mut addsession_ret = VARIANT::default();
    unsafe {
        let ret = out_params.Get(w!("ReturnValue"), 0, &mut addsession_ret, None, None);
        eprintln!("Get -> {:?}", ret);
        ret.expect("Get failure");
    }
    let sid = Variant::from_variant(&addsession_ret)?;
    eprintln!("sid: {:#?}", sid);

    Ok(0)
}
```

Current output goes like:

```
GetObject -> Ok(())
ExecMethod -> Ok(())
out_params: Some(IWbemClassObject(IUnknown(0x129ecc1cd10)))
Get -> Err(Error { code: HRESULT(0x80041002), message: "" })
```

Comment: I'd looked into this previously but ultimately gave up. This isn't a bad (or unanswerable) question. Still, the barrier to entry is pretty high: You're looking for a Rust developer who's also a Windows developer with some Citrix infrastructure at their disposal. The Citrix part ruined it for me. If you can find a "standard" WMI provider based on the same infrastructure, I'll give it another shot.

Comment: The code I show as example is mostly to be concrete, [this WMI SDK example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/example--calling-a-provider-method) can indeed be used without a specific driver - but it is much more code.
Also note that Citrix/Xenserver of XCP-ng infrastructure is not needed even for my example, this driver will work in any Xen guest domain - but right, a less specific sample case does help.

Comment: I expanded the example here: https://github.com/microsoft/windows-rs/blob/master/crates/samples/windows/wmi/src/main.rs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this particular case, which requires calling an *instance method*, requires more work than the official example from Microsoft, which showcases calling a *class method*.  This left quite some work "as an exercise for the reader".

Intuitive handling of the `VARIANT` type also requires [this windows-rs update](https://github.com/microsoft/windows-rs/pull/2794) which comes post-0.52 (don't get fooled by its summary, it does bring code changes in addition to extending the example), so until 0.53 is out you'll need to fetch the `windows` crate from git.  Which in turns [cannot work today with wmi-rs](https://github.com/ohadravid/wmi-rs/issues/88), which still works with 0.48.

The full process must then go this route:

- manual WMI session opening to get a `Wmi::IWbemServices` handle (essentially copied from `wmi-rs` and lifted to 0.52 API) - `wmi_init()` below
- call `GetObject("CitrixXenStoreBase")` on the service to get the *class object* to get the `CitrixXenStoreBase` *class object* (a  `Wmi::IWbemClassObject`) - `wmi_get_object()` below
- call `ExecQuery ("SELECT __Path FROM CitrixXenStoreBase")` on the service to get the instances of that class (other  `Wmi::IWbemClassObject`s), only collecting their `__Path` attribute, which is apparently all we need.  Since this class is a singleton, we only have to care about the first element returned by that enumerator. Inside `main()` below.
- call `GetMethod("AddSession")` on the `CitrixXenStoreBase` *class object*, to get a *class object* (yet another `Wmi::IWbemClassObject`) describing the input parameters for that method
- call its `SpawnInstance()` method to get an *instance object* (a... did you follow? `Wmi::IWbemClassObject` too) suitable to hold the actual input parameters for the method call
- call `Put()` on this object to set the sole input parameter as a named property, wrapping first the actual (string) value in a `VARIANT`
- only then call `ExecMethod` on the service (passing it the instance object's `__Path` and not the instance object itself) and get output parameters as a last `Wmi::IWbemClassObject`
- call `Get` on that output parameters object to extract the named property for the return value we're after.

As noticed by @iinspectable, yes it was quite a hike.  Thanks @kenny-kerr for hinting me to the right direction and providing `windows-rs` updates!

This is just a starting point obviously, this code will [evolve on GitHub](https://github.com/xcp-ng/xenstore-win/), and maybe at some point we'll find the right level of abstraction to add to `wmi-rs`.

```rust
pub fn wmi_init(path: &str) -> Result<Wmi::IWbemServices, WinError> {
    unsafe { Com::CoInitializeEx(None, Com::COINIT_MULTITHREADED) }?;
    unsafe { Com::CoInitializeSecurity(None,
                                       -1, // let COM choose.
                                       None,
                                       None,
                                       Com::RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_DEFAULT,
                                       Com::RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE,
                                       None,
                                       Com::EOAC_NONE,
                                       None,
    ) }?;

    // COM locator
    let loc: Wmi::IWbemLocator = unsafe {
        Com::CoCreateInstance(&Wmi::WbemLocator, None, Com::CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER)
    }?;
    // connection
    let svc = unsafe {
        loc.ConnectServer(
            &BSTR::from(path),
            &BSTR::new(),
            &BSTR::new(),
            &BSTR::new(),
            Wmi::WBEM_FLAG_CONNECT_USE_MAX_WAIT.0,
            &BSTR::new(),
            None,
        )
    }?;

    // "set proxy"
    unsafe {
        Com::CoSetProxyBlanket(
            &svc,
            Rpc::RPC_C_AUTHN_WINNT, // RPC_C_AUTHN_xxx
            Rpc::RPC_C_AUTHZ_NONE,  // RPC_C_AUTHZ_xxx
            None,
            Com::RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_CALL,      // RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_xxx
            Com::RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE, // RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_xxx
            None,                        // client identity
            Com::EOAC_NONE,              // proxy capabilities
        )
    }?;

    Ok(svc)
}

pub fn wmi_get_object(svc: &Wmi::IWbemServices, name: &str)
                      -> Result<Wmi::IWbemClassObject, WinError> {
    let mut wmi_object = None;
    unsafe { svc.GetObject(&BSTR::from(name),
                           Wmi::WBEM_FLAG_RETURN_WBEM_COMPLETE,
                           None,
                           Some(&mut wmi_object),
                           None) }?;
    // FIXME can this unwrap fail?  if missing driver?
    Ok(wmi_object.unwrap())
}

pub fn add_session(svc: &Wmi::IWbemServices,
                   xs_base_class: &Wmi::IWbemClassObject,
                   xs_base_path: &BSTR) -> Result<u32, WinError>
{
    // get input params def
    let mut in_params_class: Option<Wmi::IWbemClassObject> = None;
    unsafe { xs_base_class.GetMethod(w!("AddSession"), 0,
                                     &mut in_params_class, std::ptr::null_mut()) }?;
    let in_params_class = in_params_class.unwrap();
    // fill input params
    let in_params = unsafe { in_params_class.SpawnInstance(0) }?;
    let var_session_name = VARIANT::from("MySession");
    unsafe { in_params.Put(w!("Id"), 0, &var_session_name, 0) }?;

    // method call
    let mut out_params = None;
    unsafe { svc.ExecMethod(
        xs_base_path,
        &BSTR::from("AddSession"),
        Default::default(),
        None,
        &in_params,
        Some(&mut out_params),
        None,
    ) }?;
    let out_params = out_params.unwrap();

    // output params
    let mut sid = VARIANT::default();
    unsafe { out_params.Get(w!("SessionId"), 0, &mut sid, None, None) }?;
    let sid = u32::try_from(&sid)?;
    eprintln!("sid: {:#?}", sid);

    Ok(sid)
}

main() {
        let wmi_service = wmi_extra::wmi_init(r#"root\wmi"#)?;

        // get all instances of .CitrixXenStoreBase
        let enumerator = unsafe {
            wmi_service.ExecQuery(
                &BSTR::from("WQL"),
                &BSTR::from("SELECT __Path FROM CitrixXenStoreBase"),
                Wmi::WBEM_FLAG_FORWARD_ONLY | Wmi::WBEM_FLAG_RETURN_IMMEDIATELY,
                None,
            )
        }?;
        let mut objs = [None; 1];
        let res = {
            let mut return_value = 0;
            unsafe { enumerator.Next(Wmi::WBEM_INFINITE, &mut objs, &mut return_value) }
        };
        if let Err(e) = res.ok() {
            return Err(e.into());
        }
        // get the singleton instance
        let xenstore_base = objs.into_iter().next().unwrap().unwrap();
        let xenstore_base_class = wmi_extra::wmi_get_object(&wmi_service, "CitrixXenStoreBase")?;

        let mut xenstore_base_path = VARIANT::default();
        unsafe { xenstore_base.Get(&BSTR::from("__Path"), 0, &mut xenstore_base_path, None, None) }?;
        let xenstore_base_path = BSTR::try_from(&xenstore_base_path)?;

        // ret ...> session id
        let ret = wmi_extra::add_session(&wmi_service, &xenstore_base_class, &xenstore_base_path)?;
}
```